# Problem based on Projective and Injective Module

Tags: projective-module, injective-module

Show that the following are equivalent for a ring:

(1) any $R$-module is projective.

(2) any $R$-module is injective

This is problem in Dummit Foote book, problem number 6, page 403. I was trying by using equivalent definition of projective and injective module but nothing 
 find effective.Any help/hint in this regards would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A module $M$ is projective iff every short exact sequence
$$0\to A\to B\to M\to0$$
splits. So all modules are projective iff every short exact sequence
splits. So what about injectivity instead of projectivity
?

Comment: A module $M$ is injective iff every short exact sequence
$$0\to M\to A\to B\to0$$
splits.